# What's the difference between swiftlint:disable:next and swiftlint:disable:this?

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I'm a little confused about the differences of:

```
swiftlint:disable:next
swiftlint:disable:this
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

They're both used for *disabling* a swift rule for a single line. You can also *enable* a rule for a single line. From [SwiftLint GitHub](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint):

It's also possible to modify a `disable` or `enable` command by appending `:previous`, `:this` or `:next` for only applying the command to the previous, this (current) or next line respectively.

For example:

```
// swiftlint:disable:next force_cast
let noWarning = NSNumber() as! Int
let HASWarning = NSNumber() as! Int
let noWarning2 = NSNumber() as! Int // swiftlint:disable:this force_cast
let noWarning3 = NSNumber() as! Int
// swiftlint:disable:previous force_cast
```

You can also just disable the rule til the end of the file.

```
// swiftlint:disable force_cast
```

> The rules will be disabled until the end of the file or until the linter sees a matching enable comment:

so assuming you put it at the top of the file then the rule is disabled until it sees `// swiftlint:enable force_cast`

Or just disable each and every rule

```
// swiftlint:disable:all
```